# glutBitmapString shows nothing

Tags: opengl, freeglut

I'm going to show FPS on the screen with the freeglut function glutBitmapString,but it shows nothing. Here is my code. Is there anyone can figure where the problem is?

```
void PrintFPS()
{
    frame++;
    time=glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    if (time - timebase > 100) {
        cout << "FPS:\t"<<frame*1000.0/(time-timebase)<<endl;
        char* out = new char[30];
        sprintf(out,"FPS:%4.2f",frame*1000.0f/(time-timebase));
        glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
        glRasterPos2f(20,20);
        glutBitmapString(GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24,(unsigned char* )out);


        timebase = time;
        frame = 0;
    }
}

void RenderScene(void)
{
    // Clear the window with current clearing color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLfloat vRed[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f };
    GLfloat vYellow[] = {1.0f,1.0f,0.0f,1.0f};
    shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_IDENTITY, vYellow);
    //triangleBatch.Draw();
    squareBatch.Draw();
    PrintFPS();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

it supposed to show the FPS on the top left of the screen

Comment: Not really related to the actual problem, but `char* out = new char[30];` is never deleted, so you leak every frame. Might be better to just allocate that array on the stack.

Comment: Thank you. When I track the value of out during debug,the value was totally right.It just cannot be printed on the screen.I also tried to use glutBitmapCharacter but it still didn't work

Comment: Not enough code to really tell.  Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

The position that's provided by `glRasterPos` is treated just like a vertex, and transformed by the current model-view and projection matrices.  In you example, you specify the text to be position at (20,20), which I'm guessing is supposed to be screen (viewport, really) coordinates.

If it's the case that you're rendering 3D geometry, particularly with a perspective projection, your text may be clipped out.  However, there are (at least) two simple solutions (presented in order of code simplicity):

1. use one of the `glWindowPos` functions instead of `glRasterPos`.  This function bypasses the model-view and projection transformations.
2. use `glMatrixMode`, `glPushMatrix`, and `glPopMatrix` to temporarily switch to window coordinates for rendering:

   ```
   // Switch to window coordinates to render
   glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
   glPushMatrix();
   glLoadIdentity();    

   glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
   glPushMatrix();
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluOrtho2D( 0, windowWidth, 0, windowHeight );

   glRasterPos2i( 20, 20 );  // or wherever in window coordinates
   glutBitmapString( ... );

   glPopMatrix();
   glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
   glPopMatrix();
   ```

Comment: @DavidLively While I don't disagree, it's what the poster asked about.  I guess if the OpenGL ARB really wanted to get rid of deprecated code, they wouldn't have provided compatibility profiles along with core profiles.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant to criticize your answer, just the general state of Times Being What They Are. I've met a few guys trying to get into graphics that spend a few months punching out immediate mode code, then have to basically start over. I wish the API would default to a core profile. :)

Comment: No worries; no criticism taken.  I've seen the same thing, and on one side I completely agree with you.  On the other, whatever helps someone get their job done faster.  There's probably no great answer than whatever leaves more time for coffee :-)