# Displaying text in the corner in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

So recently i tried to do some displaying text in openGl, but i can make it appear

```
void renderBitmapString(float x, float y, char* text) {
    char *c;
    glRasterPos3f(x, y, 6.0f);
    for (c = text; *c != '\0'; c++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, *c);
    }
}
void Draw()
    {


        glPushMatrix();

        float m_amb[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
        float m_dif[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
        float m_spe[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, m_amb);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, m_dif);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, m_spe);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(place.x -5.0f, place.y -5.0f, place.z + 5.0f);

        glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(place.x + 5.0f, place.y - 5.0f, place.z + 5.0f);

        glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(place.x + 5.0f, place.y + 5.0f, place.z + 5.0f);

        glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(place.x - 5.0f, place.y + 5.0f, place.z + 5.0f);

        glEnd();

        char text[50];
        sprintf(text, "test");
        glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        renderBitmapString(90, 95, text);

        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glPopMatrix();
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    }
```

It should render a plane and 'test' in the corner, but only plane is showing. Draw() is a public function in class Menu, while renderBitmapString is global function

Comment: Shouldn't you advance the position on screen with each character printed (i.e. move the `glRasterPos3f` inside the `for` loop in `glutBitmapCharacter`?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16910494/7034621) suggest using `glWindowPos` instead of `glRasterPos`.

Comment: What is the window size respectively the viewport [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml). What is the projection matrix and the model view matrix? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Note, the z coordinate of the text is 6.0f. Is this in between the near and far plane? Is the text even on the viewport (in clip space) or is it outside at the top right?